# How could i replace fragments with intent in my navigation drawer item select

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I am using the navigation drawer method for menu but in the `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position)` void it uses this code`

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container,
            PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();`
```

but i want to use intent based on the users position selected something like

```
if (position == 1) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

and on like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using an Event bus like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto) and then publishing an event to the bus to say "this button was clicked in the drawer". Then in the parent activity you can subscribe to this event and then decide to start an activity, perform some other action, replace a fragment/etc.

This really shines when you want to make your app responsive (work well visually on a phone and tablet sized device) as on a Tablet you most likely wont have a drawer and the menu will sit fixed on the left hand side of the screen. In this case the parent activity will differ on a phone and a tablet. Using an event bus like Otto will help you decouple your application logic from UI implementation giving you more flexibility in the long run.

In the parent activity of the phone/tablet you can then fire off an intent to start the next activity/service/etc.